# Как наложить ещё одну картинку так, что бы она выходила за рамки контейнера и была во всю ширину

Tags: html, css, img

У сайта есть основной фон (голубая картинка), нужно добавить после заголовка ещё одну картинку что бы она наезжала как бы на текст, но проблема в том что эта картинка(горы) должна быть во всю ширину экрана как фон, а её ограничивает родитель, и контейнер, как быть?

```
<section id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="header-menu">
                        <img src="Img/header/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">What We Offer</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-main">
                        <h2>SKI & SNOWBOARD school</h2>
                        <h1>Stay & Ski</h1>
                    <img class="mountains"src="Img/header/mountains.png"alt="">
                        <p>The countdown to ski season has begun! So, it is hightime to improve your skills to have maximum fun this winter</p>
                        <button>online booking</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

#header {
    background: url(../Img/header/background.png) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    .header {
        &-menu {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding-top: 30px;
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                li {
                    display: inline;
                    margin-left: 15px;
                    a {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: @white;
                        .muil();
                        font-size: 16px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        &-main {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            h2 {
                text-align: center;
                .catamaran();
                color: #fefefe;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                opacity: 0.4;
                font-size: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                margin-top: 60px;
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                color: #fefefe;
                opacity: 0.4;
                font-size: 170px;
                .catamaran();
                margin-top: 0;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так примерно надо было сделать

Чуть чуть сделал адаптивным - откройте на всю страницу предосмотр и сожмите окно браузера

Тут я это делал : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YBYKvd

```js
$("span.trigger").on("click", function() {
  $("ul").toggleClass("view");
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#header {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y5bT.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

#header .header-menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#header .header-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#header .header-menu ul li {
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

#header .header-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

#header .header-main {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header .header-main h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  color: #fefefe;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0.4;
  font-size: 4.1vw;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

#header .header-main h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fefefe;
  opacity: 0.4;
  font-size: 11vw;
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header .header-main .mountains {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:695px) {
  ul li {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:640px) {
  ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #cc00cc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    transform: translateX(-200%);
    transition: 0.64s;
  }
  ul li {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .logo {
    object-fit: contain;
  }
  span.trigger {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  span.trigger i {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    margin: 6px auto;
  }
  .view {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<section id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header-menu">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rab6O.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
        <span class="trigger">
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
              </span>
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What We Offer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="header-main">
        <h2>SKI &amp; SNOWBOARD school</h2>
        <h1>Stay &amp; Ski</h1>
        <img class="mountains" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwAcf.png" alt="">
        <p>The countdown to ski season has begun! So, it is hightime to improve your skills to have maximum fun this winter</p>
        <button>online booking</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Посредством `position`: 
Задай родителю `position: relative` , а элементу `position:absolute`, и делай что угодно с этим элементом ...
Все зависит какие размеры у картинки и блока родителя ?

Comment: Выгрузил на хост, для наглядности  http://sizovleonid.ru/Ski%20&%20Snowboard%20School/

Comment: Сделай всю доступную ширину 100%(max-width) всего документа
Блоку контейнера и родителя задай также 100%
Если текст растягивается на всю ширину ограничь его , при этом задай img ширину 100% , которую он возьмет от родителя...
Второй вариант---
вынеси саму картинку за блок div и через уже известное позиционирование , оформи так как тебе нужно наложив фоном сверху

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так можна сделать

```css
#header {
    background: url(../Img/header/background.png) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    .header {
        &-menu {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding-top: 30px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 3;
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                li {
                    display: inline;
                    margin-left: 15px;
                    a {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: @white;
                        .muil();
                        font-size: 16px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        &-main {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            h2 {
                text-align: center;
                .catamaran();
                color: #fefefe;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                opacity: 0.4;
                font-size: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                margin-top: 60px;
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                color: #fefefe;
                opacity: 0.4;
                font-size: 170px;
                .catamaran();
                margin-top: 0;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            .mountains{
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="header-menu">
                        <img src="Img/header/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">What We Offer</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-main">
                        <h2>SKI & SNOWBOARD school</h2>
                        <h1>Stay & Ski</h1>
                    <img class="mountains"src="Img/header/mountains.png"alt="">
                        <p>The countdown to ski season has begun! So, it is hightime to improve your skills to have maximum fun this winter</p>
                        <button>online booking</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

или уже картинку в отдельный `div`